# How to use jitclass if class members are a dict and another class object

Tags: python-2.7, numba

I want to use jitclass to speed up my code. I defined a class B, has 2 member variables. One is a dict, the other is a object of class A. How to define spec? I've been stuck here for a while. Thank you.

I've got this:

TypeError: spec values should be Numba type instances, got

Below is the code:

```
class A(object):
    pass

spec = [
    ('x', dict),  # ------ how to write this line ?
    ('y', A),  # ------ how to write this line ?
]

@jitclass(spec)
class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = dict()
        self.y = A()
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot specify members of a `jitclass` that do not have an explicit numba type. You can make this work, however if `A` is also a `jitclass` and the `dict` is not a standard python dict, but instead is a numba typed dict (`numba.typed.Dict`). The typed dict is only supported in numba version 0.43 and later:

```
import numba as nb


@nb.jitclass([('x', nb.float64)])
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

a_type = nb.deferred_type()
dict_type = nb.deferred_type()
spec = [
    ('x', dict_type),
    ('y', a_type), 
]

a_type.define(A.class_type.instance_type)
dict_type.define(nb.typeof(nb.typed.Dict.empty(key_type=nb.int64, value_type=nb.float64)))

@nb.jitclass(spec)
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

a = A(3.0)
d = nb.typed.Dict.empty(key_type=nb.int64, value_type=nb.float64)
d[1] = 1.1
b = B(d, a)
print(b.y.x)   # => 3.0
print(b.x[1])  # => 1.1
```

Whether or not you want to or are able to use a `jitclass` for `A` or a `nb.typed.Dict` in place of a python `dict` will depend on your specific use-case.

Comment: Thank you! I tried your code. But raise an AttributeError:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'typed'.
numba has no attribute 'typed'. Why is that?

Comment: what version of numba are you using? You need at least version 0.43